# Disable minimize action in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Is there any possible way to block minimize the window (Win + D) in JavaFX?

Similar to `stage.setResizable(false);`

Comment: You could try adding a listener to the [iconified property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#iconifiedProperty--) and, if it changes, setting the property to false.  I don't run Windows (which seems to be your target platform), so I can't try this out to see if the suggestion would work under windows.